# How to deal with open ai error while it cant generate chat due to slow internet

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

Hello we are using OPEN AI chat API to generate chat ,I have noticed an issue in that when generating chat due to slow internet it cant return the message , but return an error maybe it takes more time to return a message but time out and return an error ,
So my Question is is there any way to resolve this issue

- Should play with timeout
- Is there ay other Good Way to resolve that